# Typescript how to dynamically access methods of a class using variables as

Tags: typescript

How can i make TS work with this code?

```
export class Bla {
  do1() {
    return 1;
  }

  do2() {
    const lista = ['do1'];
    lista.every((i): string => {
      return this[i](); ->>Error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Bla'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Bla'
    });
  }
}
```

The error occurs in the **this**.
I saw this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680507/typescript-define-a-string-variable-as-a-method-of-a-class) but in my case in not an abstract class. I also read this [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) which might be a way to solve this, but i can't figure it out.
Anyone knows how to solve this TS error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array as const. It's going to be like this:

```js
export class Bla {
  do1() {
    return 1;
  }

  do2() {
    const lista = ['do1'] as const;   // <- Here
    lista.every((i) => {
      return this[i]();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Still need this lista.every((i): any => ... But it worked! Thank you.